# Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, heroku

I have problem when i try to push my app on heroku,
so when i write git push heroku master this error is appear

```
    remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-48na90v5/importlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-48na90v5/importlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-dccx97n0       
    remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-48na90v5/importlib/
    remote:            Complete output (11 lines):
    remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
    remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    remote:                import distutils.core
    remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 16, in <module>
    remote:                from distutils.dist import Distribution
    remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 19, in <module>
    remote:                from distutils.util import check_environ, strtobool, rfc822_escape
    remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/util.py", line 9, in <module>
    remote:                import importlib.util
    remote:            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'
    remote:            ----------------------------------------
    remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is the issue with libraries you are trying to install check for the versions as currently heroku uses latest version of python

or just change the python version specific to your project on heroku by using runtime.txt file in your root directory

I had also faced the exact same issue which I fixed by installing latest versions of the dependencies.

Try; definitely it will work.